# Multiple gates for a flowSet using flowViz

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I want to use multiple ellipsoid gates on a `flowSet` and plot the result.

I manage to plot the `flowSet` with one gate per frame, but I can't construct the `filtersList` object correctly. I get the following warning:

`Warning messages:
1: 'filter' must either be a filtersList,filterResultList, a single
filter object or a named list of filter objects.
2: 'filter' must either be a filtersList,filterResultList, a single
filter object or a named list of filter objects.`

```
set.seed(1)
library(flowViz)
# Graphical parameters
flowViz.par.set("gate", list(lwd = 8))
gp <- flowViz.par.get()

# First set of data
data1 <- matrix(c(rnorm(10000), rlnorm(10000)), ncol = 2)
colnames(data1) <- c("M1", "M2")
rownames(data1) <- 1:10000

# Second set of data
data2 <- matrix(c(rnorm(10000), rlnorm(10000)), ncol = 2)
colnames(data2) <- c("M1", "M2")
rownames(data2) <- 1:10000

# Constructing the flowFrames
frame1 <- new("flowFrame", exprs = data1)
frame2 <- new("flowFrame", exprs = data2)

# Gating 
covar1 <- matrix(c(1,0.001,0.001,5), ncol = 2)
colnames(covar1) <- c("M1", "M2")
rownames(covar1) <- c("M1", "M2")
covar2 <- covar1 

means1 <- c(M1 = 0, M2 = 2.5)
means2 <- c(M1 = 0, M2 = 10)

eg1 <- ellipsoidGate(.gate = covar1, mean = means1)
eg2 <- ellipsoidGate(.gate = covar2, mean = means2)

egs <- filters(list(gate1 = eg1, gate2 = eg2))

# Plotting only one flowFrame
xyplot(`M2`~`M1`, frame1, xlab = "M2", ylab = "M1", xlim = c(-4,4), 
ylim = c(0,30), smooth = FALSE, filter = egs)
```

[image: Plotting only one flowFrame]

Now the same for a `flowSet`.

```
# Constructing the flowSet
frames <- list(frame1, frame2)
fs <- flowSet(frames)

# Plotting the flowSet
xyplot(`M2`~`M1`|name, fs, xlab = "M2", ylab = "M1", xlim = c(-4,4), 
ylim = c(0,30), 
       panel = function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot.flowset(x = x, frames = fs, channel.x.name = "M1",
                              channel.y.name = "M2",gp = gp, 
                              smooth = FALSE,  filter = eg1)
   })
```

[image: Plotting a flowSet with one filter]

Now I want to construct a `filtersList` to use multiple gates for each `flowFrame` of my `flowSet`.

```
# Constructing the filtersList
myFilters <- filtersList(list(plot1 = egs, plot2 = egs))

xyplot(`M2`~`M1`|name, fs, xlab = "M2", ylab = "M1", xlim = c(-4,4), 
ylim = c(0,30), 
       panel = function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot.flowset(x = x, frames = fs, channel.x.name = "M1",
 channel.y.name = "M2", gp = gp, smooth = FALSE,  filter = myFilters)
       })
```

[image: Plotting a flowSet]

At this point I get the warning posted above. So, how do I construct the `filtersList` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. You just have to construct `filters` object from a list of your gates.

Then repeat the object so you get a list of `filters` the same length as your `flowset` and name the `list` elements the same as your `flowset` elements.

But you can only use gates of the same type, so you cannot combine `rectangleGate` and `ellipsoidGate` objects.

```
# Constructing the filtersList  
myFilters <- filters(list(eg1,eg2))  
myFilters <- rep(list(myFilters),2)  
names(myFilters) <- sampleNames(fs)  

xyplot(`M2`~`M1`|name, fs, xlab = "M2", ylab = "M1", xlim = c(-4,4),  
      ylim = c(0,30),  
      panel = function(x,y,...){  
        panel.xyplot.flowset(x = x, frames = fs, channel.x.name = "M1",  
                             channel.y.name = "M2", gp = gp, smooth = FALSE,  
                             filter = myFilters)  
      })
```

[image: flowSet with 2 different gates per panel]